# Displaying styled validation messages to user using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and jQuery, Just for test I created this simple code. When the user enters their **First Name** and their **Last Name** it displays a message that says `Thanks for entering everything correctly!` in **Bluish** color, and when the user forgets to enter their **First Name** and their **Last Name** it displays an error that says `You didn't entered anything` in **Red** color or something similar  And yeah I know it sounds stupid but this just testing... So here is my code:

> **change_name.php**:

```
function displayError($error)
{
    // Display a div with a class of error, We style it using CSS
    echo "<div class='error'>$error</div><br>";
}

function displayMessage($message)
{
    // Display a div with a class of message, We style it using CSS
    echo "<div class='message'>$message</div> <br>";
}


if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['first_name']) && empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
        displayError('You didn\'t entered anything!');
    } else if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
        displayError('You didn\'t entered your first name!');
    } else if (empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
        displayError('You didn\'t entered your last name!');
    } else {
        displayMessage('Thanks for entering everything correctly!');
    }
}
```

> **JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nameChange').on('submit', function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'ajax/change_name.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
               $('.result').empty().append(data);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

> **index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery AJAX</title>

    <style>
        .message {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            color: #00AAE9;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .error {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            color: #E70000;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="ajax/change_name.php" method="POST" id="nameChange">

        Result: <div class="result"></div>


        <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
        <br>

        <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">        
        <br>

        <input type="submit" name="change_name" value="Change" id="change_name">
    </form>


    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: Is it a good practice to display a `<div>` and then add a class to it, so you can then style it using CSS? Is there a better way for doing this? Can't you just return a JSON response and access it using JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, is better to just retrieve the text and the result (error or success) and change the class using etc. `.addClass('success/fail')` on receiving element than downloading new elements with classes in it.

Comment: Thanks, Like I said I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript in general, Can you tell me how I know if it's success or it's fail?

Comment: there is a whole plug in for jquery that will do your validation and its pretty easy to learn, No reason to re-create teh wheel....

Comment: @Akar, check my simple approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this for every case i need a TRUE/FALSE result from server, accompanied with some information:

**PHP**

```
// $_POST values are just examples
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST"]=="POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["username"]) || strlen($_POST["username"])<3) {
       echo json_encode(array("result"=>FALSE,"class"=>"fail","message"=>"Your username can't be empty or less than 3 characters"));
       return;
    }
    ...
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>TRUE,"class"=>"success","message"=>"Success");
    return;
}
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST', 
   url: 'ajax/change_name.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   dataType: "JSON",            <----
   success: function(data) {
      $('.result').removeClass().addClass("."+data["class"]).html(data["message"]);
   }                                                 --^            ------^
});
```

This may looks a bit ugly :) though

Comment: It works perfectly! I cleaned it up a bit. and you don't really need that `.` in front of `data['class]`, So instead of `addClass('.'+ data['class'])` It should be `addClass(data['class'])`, Thanks!